# Why does VS Code's yaml extension classify period as a float?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml

I was in the process of developing my own colour theme. I tried to make a custom colouring for `.yml` files when I stumbled upon that VS Code's YAML extension is interpreting *period* as a *float*.

Is this the right behaviour? Shouldn't it be interpreted as a plain unquoted string?

Stripped version of the regex that defines grammar. It'll successfully match period. [Actual code.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/yaml/syntaxes/yaml.tmLanguage.json#L502)

```regex
(?x:[-+]? (?: [0-9] [0-9_]*)? \. [0-9.]* (?: [eE] [-+] [0-9]+)?)
```

[Screenshot using "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXTni.png)

Comment: I don't use VS Code, but I suspect it is something controlled by context. The `'.'` can be used for floating-point as well as struct and class member access and in a host of other situations depending on language and context. So I don't know, without more, if it can be characterized as a right or wrong issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right behavior for YAML 1.2. According to [the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804092), the canonical form is

> Either `0`, `.inf`, `-.inf`, `.nan`, or scientific notation matching the regular expression `-? [1-9] ( \. [0-9]* [1-9] )? ( e [-+] [1-9] [0-9]* )?`.

[Further down](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) another regex is given for recognizing a float in the core schema, which is more relaxed:

> ```
> [-+]? ( \. [0-9]+ | [0-9]+ ( \. [0-9]* )? ) ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+ )?
> ```

That still doesn't match a single period.

However, it *is* the correct behavior for YAML 1.1. Here, the regex for floats [given in the type registry](https://yaml.org/type/float.html) is

> ```
> [-+]?([0-9][0-9_]*)?\.[0-9.]*([eE][-+][0-9]+)?
> ```

This is very likely the source of the regex, given that it matches apart from meta stuff.

Adoption for YAML 1.2 was very slow, with some implementations only gaining support in recent years, and some (e.g. SnakeYAML) still being stuck at YAML 1.1. Therefore, it is not an obvious decision to use the YAML 1.2 regex.